# Unable to recreate Private Service Access on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

Following the guide at https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-services-access , I managed to create a private service access connection. However, the second time around (after deleting the existing ones), I'm getting a cryptic error which I'm unable to find a reference to anywhere. Here's the error:

```
Cannot modify reserved ranges in CreateConnection. Please use UpdateConnection.
```

Comment: Using a different name for the VPC seems to work around this issue.

Comment: By changing the VPC, you are changing which resources (located in a VPC) that can connect over the peered connection. Currently only Cloud SQL and third party services are supported by Private Service Access. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to use Cloud SQL through a VPC network as to avoid exposing the server to public Internet and having to define IP whitelist (which is the main purpose of this private service access).

Comment: OK - you are using the correct service feature for Cloud SQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error you are experiencing is expected as currently it's not possible to modify the range you reserved after it is created. This is collected on the [GCP official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/private-ip#administration_considerations):

> After you have established a private services access connection, and
>   created a Cloud SQL instance with private IP configured for that
>   connection, the corresponding (internal) subnet and range used by the
>   Cloud SQL service cannot be modified or deleted. This is true even if
>   you delete the peering and your IP range.

There is a current public [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123276199) for this since more users reported the same.

By now, current "solution" is to create another VPC for this as you did.

Comment: Accordingly to the Feature request "engineering team responsible for the Cloud SQL have recently **deployed a fix allowing you to modify the subnet and IP used for Cloud SQL instances using Private IP**.". No need to recreate VPC if you use `--force` flag as described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56743836/12428794

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue by mistakenly removing the peering...

But, It is possible to reconnect the peering (or update it) by updating the gcloud SDK and run a gcloud command:

> $ gcloud components update
>
> $ gcloud services vpc-peerings connect --service=servicenetworking.googleapis.com --ranges=[private_connection_range_name] --network=[vpc_network_name] --project=[project_name]
>
> ERROR: (gcloud.services.vpc-peerings.connect) The operation
>   "operations/pssn.XXXXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" resulted in a
>   failure "Cannot modify allocated ranges in CreateConnection. Please
>   use UpdateConnection.".
>
> Details: "[]".
>
> $ gcloud services vpc-peerings update --service=servicenetworking.googleapis.com --ranges=[private_connection_range_name] --network=[vpc_network_name]  --project=[project_name] --force
>
> Operation "operations/pssn.XXXXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" finished Successfully.

To find your private connection range name:

> gcloud compute addresses list --global --filter="purpose=VPC_PEERING"

If you have not created one manually, by default, the name is: 
**google-managed-services-[vpc_network_name]**

source: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-services-access

Once googleapis peering is up, the CloudSQL peering brings up alone too

Regards.

Comment: Thanks, this had me banging my head on a wall for ages! It seems forcing the vpc peering update and then manually removing it via the console cleared the issue for me - further updates worked successfully.

Comment: Awesome @Michaël Lopez, this command `gcloud services vpc-peerings update --service=servicenetworking.googleapis.com --ranges=[private_connection_range_name] --network=[vpc_network_name] --project=[project_name] --force` worked for me. By the way I was trying to do it via terraform, So I had to manually execute your command once and then had do the same via terraform, adding my answer here. !!!

Answer (score 6):

Use the below command to update your connection.  No need to recreate new VPC

```
gcloud beta services vpc-peerings update \
    --service=servicenetworking.googleapis.com \
    --ranges=[your-private-connection-range-name] \
    --network=[your-vpc-name] \
    --project=[your-project-id] \
    --force
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is attempting to achieve the same task using Terraform, here's the code. You don't need to create another VPC if you're utilizing Terraform.

```
resource "google_service_networking_connection" "tf_private_vpc" {
  provider                = google
  network                 = google_compute_network.tf_private_network.id
  service                 = "servicenetworking.googleapis.com"
  reserved_peering_ranges = [google_compute_global_address.tf_private_ip.name]

   #Force deletion of the existing resource when the configuration changes

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = false
    ignore_changes = [reserved_peering_ranges]
  }
}
```

[image]

Just a heads up, this is tailored to my specific use case. I'm setting up Cloud SQL for both development and production environments using Terraform, hence I've had to test my script multiple times to ensure everything works smoothly.