# Sqlcmd error while connecting with SQL Server instance on a VM using SQL Server proxy

Tags: sql-server, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

I have created a private SQL Server instance and trying to access it on Virtual Machine instance using SQL Server proxy using the link (https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/connect-instance-private-ip) on GCP platform

It worked well but today it was throwing the below 2 errors repeatedly while running the `sqlcmd` command

```
sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1 -U sqlserver
```

Error:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Timeout error [258].
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Unable to complete login process due to delay in prelogin response.

and

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2749.
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

I am not sure how to resolve these issues.

Comment: The Cloud SQL Auth Proxy is a process running on your local computer that provides a tunnel over the internet to your Cloud SQL instance's private IP address. Did you remember to start it with something like `./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME=tcp:1433` before running sqlcmd?

Comment: yes I did run the above command in another SSH window

Comment: you need to run it on your local computer - or at least from wherever you're executing `sqlcmd`. Running it inside an SSH window is probably running it on a different, remote computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above issue might occur when the private service access connection breaks for the SQL server instance on GCP platform. That is when some one mistakenly removes the peering.
The above error resolves when we create/update the existing peering connection. The solution is posted in the link [Unable to recreate Private Service Access on GCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55135559/unable-to-recreate-private-service-access-on-gcp/56743836#56743836)

Answer (score 3):

When connecting to Cloud SQL via Cloud SQL Auth proxy, it is a requirement to start the proxy every time you attempt to connect to Cloud SQL as mentioned by @AlwaysLearning. I was able to reproduced your error and starting the Cloud SQL Auth proxy solved the problem.

Connecting to Cloud SQL without starting Cloud SQL Auth proxy:

[image]

As stated in the documentation you referenced, you [start the Cloud SQL Auth proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/connect-instance-private-ip#start-proxy) using this command:

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME=tcp:1433
```

[image]

[image]

Additionally if your Compute Engine instance is in the same region as your Cloud SQL instance, you may want to consider another way to connect these instances. In the [Connect from Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/connect-compute-engine#connect-gce-private-ip) documentation, you can find the instructions on how to connect from a CE instance to a private IP of a Cloud SQL instance as long as both of these instances are on the same region.

Comment: I have also run the sqlproxy using the above command in another ssh window. But no change the error still persists. Connection Timed out error

Comment: @SasirekhaMSVL can you share the result in the SSH window when you started the sqlproxy?